# how to tell if ffmpeg is capturing all of the frames from a video stream

Tags: ffmpeg, video-capture

I am trying to use `ffmpeg` to record video from a capture card. I have previously recorded the video using a raw format (e.g. `ffmpeg -i /dev/video0 -c:v copy out.mkv`) and then converted the mkv to a compressed mp4. But I have been trying to do the recording and conversion at once, e.g. `ffmpeg -i /dev/video0 -c:v libx265 out.mp4`. However, the card outputs video at 30 fps, and saving the video with a codec like H.265 is computationally demanding, so it is unclear to me if all the frames are being captured.

There are three values that `ffmpeg` outputs which I've been trying to use to figure out if frames are missed: `fps=`, `dup=` and `drop=`. I believe `fps=` is some sort of moving average, and it isn't clear to me when frames are missed. Also, I don't believe the `drop=` values are the same as what I'm interested in (i.e. frames that were "missed" from the stream). Finally, I think the `dup=` values might be relevant, but it's not exactly clear to me if a duplicated frame corresponds to a missed frame from the stream.

**How can I determine if the captured video misses frames from the stream?**

Comment: Ffmpeg will not skip frames when capturing this way. If the encode is keeping up, all the frames are captured.

Comment: But how do I tell if the encoding is keeping up? I've tested this on a slower laptop which is too slow to capture all of the frames. In that case, it shows an fps below 30. On a faster laptop, it isn't clear to me if all the frames are captured (the fps is about 30 but I get some drops and dups).